# First Android App (Java) - Why is this crashing? It is default code

Tags: java, android, emulation, oncreate

I cannot seem to get this to run, even if it is default code. However, if I delete the default `onCreate` method, it works just fine. This doesn't allow me to code anything though. Hopefully someone can point a noob in the right direction. Thanks!

```
package com.example.danielgannage.randomizer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

However, if I remove:
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

it will run just fine.

Comment: post the error.

Comment: all it says in the emulator is: "This app failed to open."

Comment: Use this **`resultsTextView.setText(String.valueOf(woo));`** instead of this `resultsTextView.setText(woo);`

Comment: Instead of resultsTextView.setText(woo) use resultsTextView.setText(String.valueOf(woo));

Comment: I did, that changed nothing

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
resultsTextView.setText(woo);
```

with

```
resultsTextView.setText(String.valueOf(woo));
```